# Como utilizar TAnimate no Delphi

Tags: delphi, thread, animação

Olá,
Estou querendo utilizar a ferramenta TAnimate, porem ela não tem nenhuma animação nela, onde eu pesquisei diz que já vem junto com a ferramenta. Sabem me dizer se tem que declarar algo junto? ou onde posso conseguir essas animações?
Elas consumem muita Thread só sistema também? ou usa uma independente da que o programa roda?

Comment: De uma olhada para ver se ajuda: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1492799/how-do-i-get-tanimates-common-avis-to-work-on-vista-and-win7?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: oi, na verdade não, pois tenho problema na animação que ja vem junto com o componente, e como se ela não existisse...

Comment: A dica do colega, é tentar colocar o `ShellAnimations` no uses da unit. Se isso não funciona, por favor adicione seu código para melhor analise dos colaboradores.

Comment: Então, eu ja tentei, mas acho que o componente esta com problema ou o meu Delphi não tem o componente completo(uso Delphi 2006),
pois no meu caso, eu coloco o TAnimate e nas propriedades, no 'comonAVI', que teria ja alguns por 'padrão' ele não executa, somente se eu pelo 'filename', escolher um. Se souber onde conseguir esses AVI para colocar ja seria ótimo, pois não acho nada, somente os pagos...

Answer (score 1):

Amigo,

Eu utilizo o TRxGIFAnimator do pacote RxLib (http://www.micrel.cz/RxLib/) onde o mesmo é free....
Para isto vai precisar de um gif animado (tem um monte na intenet).
É só carregar o gif e para começar a animação dar um True na propriedade Animate...